# Why can't I change the "Emulated Performance: Graphics" setting in the Android Virtual Device configuration?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, settings

I'm trying to set up Flutter using Android Studio, and I'm setting up a Virtual Device using the Android Virtual Device window under Tools.  It specifies in [these](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#set-up-the-android-emulator) instructions to change the `Emulated Performance: Graphics` setting to `Hardware - GLES 2.0`, but the window won't let me change the setting from `Automatic`.  Can anyone explain how I *can* change this setting?  Thanks!
[image]

Screenshot:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Google play images** that run on a device like pixel or nexus 5(x), can only accept automatic graphic acceleration. so if you don't need Google play features then you can select another images