# In android studio Go to: Tools > Android > AVD Manager Press the "edit" (pencil) icon next to your AVD Change "Graphics" to "Software"

Tags: android, sdk

Graphics to Software is not coming. It shows a disabled dropdown in front of graphics option

Comment: have a look [at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016119/why-cant-i-change-the-emulated-performance-graphics-setting-in-the-android-v)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

@Tabish, in my android studio i can see this option for android virtual device i created. I am using android studio 3.3

Comment: yeah that dropdown(where software is written) is disabled in my android studio

Comment: @tabish try starting avd using command line. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#command-gpu